# Restrict a generic type parameter to the callers static type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

An immutable sub class inherits a property from an abstract base class (for some kind of a strategy pattern). I am looking for a reusable implementation of an immutable setter method `WithValue` in the base class that returns the static type of the caller, without having to surface any generics in the fluent syntax.

```cs
public abstract class BaseX
{
    public string Value { get; init; }

    public BaseX(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T WithValue<T>(string value) where T : BaseX, new()
    {
        T newX = new()
        {
            Value = value
        };
        return newX;
    }

}

public class SubA : BaseX
{

    public SubA() : base("A") { }

    public void DoAishStuff() { ... }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is this:

```cs
SubA a = new();
a.WithValue("foo").DoAishStuff(); // fluent syntax
```

But this actually requires a type argument `a.WithValue<SubA>(...)`, which is not nice to write, and would allow to use other subtypes like `SubB`.

I can accomplish the desired syntax with an extension method:

```cs
public static class BaseXExtensions
{
    public static T WithValue<T>(this T self, string value) where T : BaseX, new()
    {
        T obj = new()
        {
            Value = value
        };
        return obj;
    }
}
```

However, it seems a little strange that I can't integrate this mechanism into the base class itself. Basically what I'm looking for is a constraint like `where T : this`. Are there other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the base class itself a generic, and define its constraint in terms of itself.

```
public abstract class BaseX<T> where T : BaseX<T>, new()
{
    public string Value { get; init; }

    protected BaseX(string value) => Value = value;

    public T WithValue(string value) => new() { Value = value };
}
```

Your subclasses then inherit from that base class:

```
public class SubA : BaseX<SubA>
{
    public SubA() : base("A") { }

    public void DoAishStuff() { ... }
}
```

I sometimes use both a non-generic base class and a generic base class that inherits from the non-generic. This allows you to handle edge cases with `BaseX` and normal cases with `BaseX<T>`.

Consider,

```
public abstract class BaseX
{
    public string Value { get; protected init; }

    protected BaseX(string value) => Value = value;
}

public abstract class BaseX<T> : BaseX where T : BaseX<T>, new()
{
    protected BaseX(string value) : base(value)
    {}

    public T WithValue(string value) => new() { Value = value };
}

public class SubB : BaseX
{
    public SubB() : base("B") { }

    // one off way of doing WithValue() for BaseX
    public SubB WithValue(string value) => new SubB("'" + value + "'");
}

public class SubA : BaseX<SubA>
{
    public SubA() : base("A") { }

    public void DoAishStuff() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Non-generic types are easier to handle, so the combination of a self-referencing generic class with a non-generic base class is indeed a very useful pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can try leveraging [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) (available since C# 9):

```cs
public abstract class BaseX
{
    public string Value { get; init; }

    public BaseX(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public abstract BaseX WithValue(string value);
    
    protected T WithValueInternal<T>(string value) where T : BaseX, new()
    {
        T newX = new()
        {
            Value = value
        };
        return newX;
    }
}

public class SubA : BaseX
{
    public SubA() : base("A") { }

    public void DoAishStuff() { }
    
    public override SubA WithValue(string value) => WithValueInternal<SubA>(value);
}
```

Which allows `a.WithValue("foo").DoAishStuff();`

You can introduce an interim generic class (with [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) so you don't need to override the `WithValue` method in inheritors:

```cs
public abstract class BaseXX<T>: BaseX where T : BaseX, new()
{
    public BaseXX(string value) : base("A") { }
    public override T WithValue(string value) => WithValueInternal<T>(value);
}

public class SubA : BaseXX<SubA>
{
    public SubA() : base("A") { }

    public void DoAishStuff() { }
}
```

Also note that [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) support very similar [nondestructive mutation via `with` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation).